# problems by User URL - htacces

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop

this is so that I get an error when I work with preatashop, and I get a 404 error and I can not possibly see the error.

error on my hosting are here:

```
[Tue Mar 18 16:29:31.837809 2014] [:error] [pid 381031] [client 188.181.88.9:42136] 
SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group, referer: http://www.shop-bo.dk/index.php
[Tue Mar 18 16:23:45.421181 2014] [:error] [pid 375394] [client 183.81.54.21:40210] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group, referer: http://www.shop-bo.dk/admin123/index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=52745cf84f136fef00d2738ad3be8887&configure=blockadvfooter&tab_module=others&module_name=blockadvfooter
[Tue Mar 18 16:22:34.397894 2014] [:error] [pid 373007] [client 183.81.54.21:39642] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group, referer: http://www.shop-bo.dk/admin123/index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=52745cf84f136fef00d2738ad3be8887&configure=blockadvfooter&tab_module=others&module_name=blockadvfooter
[Tue Mar 18 16:20:13.975016 2014] [:error] [pid 368791] [client 188.181.88.9:38718] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group, referer: http://www.shop-bo.dk/admin123/index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=c743f4f33c0588a21fa3880e5772bf6c&configure=blockadvfooter&tab_module=others&module_name=blockadvfooter
[Tue Mar 18 16:19:35.680863 2014] [:error] [pid 368791] [client 183.81.54.21:38415] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group, referer: http://www.shop-bo.dk/index.php
[Tue Mar 18 16:19:32.283604 2014] [:error] [pid 367335] [client 183.81.54.21:38408] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group
[Tue Mar 18 16:18:58.956017 2014] [:error] [pid 371329] [client 183.81.54.21:38290] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group, referer: http://www.shop-bo.dk/admin123/index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=52745cf84f136fef00d2738ad3be8887&configure=blockadvfooter&tab_module=others&module_name=blockadvfooter
[Tue Mar 18 16:18:54.456715 2014] [:error] [pid 369337] [client 188.181.88.9:38293] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group, referer: http://www.shop-bo.dk/index.php
[Tue Mar 18 16:18:33.148207 2014] [:error] [pid 369336] [client 183.81.54.21:38191] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group, referer: http://www.shop-bo.dk/index.php
[Tue Mar 18 16:18:24.373591 2014] [:error] [pid 359359] [client 183.81.54.21:38139] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group, referer: http://www.shop-bo.dk/index.php
[Tue Mar 18 16:18:18.820409 2014] [:error] [pid 368791] [client 183.81.54.21:38121] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group
[Tue Mar 18 16:17:52.208217 2014] [:error] [pid 369336] [client 183.81.54.21:37992] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group, referer: http://www.shop-bo.dk/index.php
[Tue Mar 18 16:17:45.449577 2014] [:error] [pid 368791] [client 183.81.54.21:37955] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group
[Tue Mar 18 16:17:32.821418 2014] [:error] [pid 369336] [client 183.81.54.21:37852] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group
[Tue Mar 18 16:16:23.042423 2014] [:error] [pid 367335] [client 183.81.54.21:37511] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group
[Tue Mar 18 16:15:57.751759 2014] [:error] [pid 367335] [client 183.81.54.21:37445] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group
[Tue Mar 18 16:15:49.707305 2014] [:error] [pid 361467] [client 188.181.88.9:37419] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group
[Tue Mar 18 16:15:38.862260 2014] [:error] [pid 369137] [client 183.81.54.21:37391] SoftException in Application.cpp:601: Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group
```

I have set to be user-friendly URL - htacces

my .htaccess its here:

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo4leotheme.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/prestashop/leo_mobile/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo4leotheme.com$
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /prestashop/leo_mobile/index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `error.log` shows something important:

```
Directory "/home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules" is writeable by group
```

Fix this error by changing your permissions using this `chmod` command:

```
chmod g-w /home/jesperbo/public_html/shop-bo.dk/modules
```

Comment: what do you mean completely?, what should I do?

Comment: Completely separate issue from .htaccess. Anyone sharing your _group_ can overwrite that directory, which would normally not be good. Assuming that PHP is not running in your group _and_ does not need to write to that directory, change the permissions to take away "write".

Comment: @user3187390: You need to run that `chmod` command on unix command line.

Comment: @anubhava in .htaccess file or where?

Comment: Unix commands are not run in .htaccess but on Unix command line (in terminal). If you are not aware ask your system admin to do it for you.

Comment: so it means that it is only hosting can be right in the files, then I may get in touch with them and hear them, it is really understood? @anubhava

Comment: I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @anubhava sorry, i mean -> f that's how they're doing it that you have written then it should very much like to work here for?

Comment: Yes from your error.log it appears to be the problem. If you still encounter a different problem feel free to comment here or create a new question so that you get help here.